# Vuex return null in Ajax query (first send)

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I send email and password to Vuex:

```
this.$store.dispatch('login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
}).then(console.log(this.$store.state.login));
```

In Vuex I use Axios, this code is on `actions`:

```
    login(context, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let options = {
                method: "post",
                data: payload,
                url: "/api/login"
            };
            axios(options)
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit("login", response.data);
                    resolve();
                })
        });
    },
```

next I send data to the `mutations`:

```
login(state, login){
    state.login = login;
},
```

And to the `state`:

```
login: null
```

This is form:

```
<form method="post" @submit.prevent="sendLogin">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" v-model="email">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" v-model="password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I write `email` and `password` and click FIRST time `Submit` `.then(console.log(this.$store.state.login));` return `NULL`, but when I second click `Submit` `log` return correctly data.

**How I can resolve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start here:

```js
}).then(console.log(this.$store.state.login));
```

This is calling `console.log` immediately and passing its return value, `undefined`, to `then`. It's equivalent to writing this:

```js
const loginPromise = this.$store.dispatch('login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
});

const x = console.log(this.$store.state.login);

loginPromise.then(x);
```

So at the point the logging occurs the asynchronous login will not have completed and the value logged will be `null`.

What you need is to wrap your logging in a function:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('login', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
}).then(() => {
    console.log(this.$store.state.login);
});
```

That should be sufficient but I would also note that the way you're creating a new Promise is likely unnecessary in your store. It should be possible to write it as this instead:

```js
login(context, payload) {
    const options = {
        method: "post",
        data: payload,
        url: "/api/login"
    };

    return axios(options)
        .then(response => {
            context.commit("login", response.data);
        });
    },
```

So this will just return the promise that's returned by the `then` call.

You should rarely need to use the constructor to create a new promise. There are legitimate use cases but in cases where you already have a promise you should generally use some form of `then` chaining instead. See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)